# android : need to show cached images in webview

Tags: android

In my android app, i have webview and showing some html data in it.
In HTML data,there are some img tags also.

I have puta check for internet connectivity like this::

```
String html = this.gn.renderHTML( sXMLDef, iScreenWidth, density);  
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    String offlineimg = "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/offline.png\"/>";
    if(!isConnected){
        String str[] = html.split("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            if(str[i].startsWith("<img")){
                html = html.replace(str[i], offlineimg);
                wvBrowser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            }

        }

    }

    wvBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL( sBanner, html, this.mimeType,
            this.encoding, null );
```

before adding internetc check, images were coming even if user is offline.

once i put internet check it just shows offline.png, if no internet avaliable. Ideally it shold show the cacheded images, if no internet and offline png, if imge is not cached or page has not loaded yet.

Below is generated html::

```
<img onclick="javascript:location.href = 'pic://' + this.src;"    class="picture" align="MIDDLE" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/iphonecde/_PNYCOOL.GIF"/></div><br />
<br />
<div class='captiontitle'><b>Built Into a Graphics Card</b></div><br    />
<div class='caption'>This PNY graphics card comes with its own cooling  system that also cools the CPU.  The radiator and fan (left) cool the water coming from the card, and the center unit is placed over the CPU.    <i>(Image courtesy of PNY Technologies, www.pny.com)</i></div><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div align="center">
<img onclick="javascript:location.href = 'pic://' + this.src;"      class="picture" align="MIDDLE" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/iphonecde/_COOLR3.JPG"/></div><br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming lot of things in your code:

1. HTML has a line feed (\n) for every line !
   In most cases this is not the case
2. tag is always at the beginning of a new line !
   Once again the assumption is most not true
   Atleast, trim() the text before this search
3. You are managing your own caching, setting cache parameters for the webview is immaterial

My guess the error is (1) or (2) above.  Paste your regenerated HTML to give your more information.

Comment: Added  html in the question....Actually i have stored my data in the sqlite database in xml form and then converting xml to html. I have put /n after every tag....